# Windows phone 7 debug sidebar

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7

When developing a wp7 app, every time I debug, a weird sidebar appears in the right side of the emulator and phone.

How can I hide this annoying bar? What is it for?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows you useful debuging info, see http://www.pchenry.com/Home/tabid/36/EntryId/348/How-to-turn-off-the-WP7-performance-glyphs-in-your-emulator.aspx for explanation.

If you do not want to have it displayed, run it app in `Release` instead of `Debug` but I would not really recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Igor Kulman's answer, you can also change the `EnableFrameRateCounter` property in the constructor of the App.xaml.cs file:

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false;
```

This way you'll can still run in Debug.